# undefined method `scan' for #<Hash:0x00000004effe80>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I get the below error when i try to run my `specs`.

```
Failure/Error: user = User.find({id: 2856, authorization: token});
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `scan' for #<Hash:0x00000004effe80>
```

Below is my `spec`.

```
 #Spec for user find and current user
  context "when user exists" do    
    it "should find a user" do 
      user = User.find({id: 2856, authorization: token});
      expect(user.name).to eq("test")
    end      
  end
```

Comment: This looks like `user.name` is returning a hash instead of a string, which is odd.  Can you inspect (in puts or logging) the value of `user`, before you do the expect test?

Comment: Can anyone tell me why a negative vote is given?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Downvoting seems harsh here: it's obvious that the question is "why am i getting the error?".

Comment: I also think that, because this is probably a common trap that people will fall into due to the change in the Rails API, this is a good question.

Answer (score 2):

[`find`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find) method search only by `id` in last Rails version, so instead:

```
  context "when user exists" do    
    it "should find a user" do 
      user = User.find({id: 2856, authorization: token});
      expect(user.name).to eq("test")
    end      
  end
```

Use:

```
  context "when user exists" do    
    it "should find a user" do 
      user = User.where(id: 2856, authorization: token).first
      expect(user.name).to eq("test")
    end      
  end
```

Or better:

```
  context "when user exists" do    
    it "should find a user" do 
      user = User.where(authorization: token).find(2856)
      expect(user.name).to eq("test")
    end      
  end
```